# iOS Set up NSTimer to call a method only on active / inactive page

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I one of my ViewController I want to call a method `updateVisitotsLists` on some time criteria's and am not able to decide which way will be best to achieve it.

1) Every time the view is loaded/appeared I want to call this method.

For this in viewDidAppear method I can call this before calling [super viewDidAppear];, so that works, I believe.

2) If user is on this view only, then I want to call this method after every 5 secs.

For this, I need to set a NSTimer. I want to stop this timer when viewDidDisappear - as don't want it running unnecessary. Should I use an UnScheduled Timer as shown [here](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/objective-c-using-nstimer/) and start and stop in appear & disappear methods ? In viewDidAppear, initially I call this method, and then also set

```
NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0
                  target: self
                  selector:@selector(updateVisitotsLists:)
                  userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
```

What will be the best way and methodology to achieve what I am looking for ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATED :-

@Lord Zolt, as per your comment I did the following :-

```
 //In .h
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer; 

 // .m 
 @synthesize timer;

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    ........

   [super viewDidLoad];

   // CREATE TIMER
   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(onTimerCall:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }

 -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }

 -(void) onTimerCall: (NSTimer *) _timer {
    // UPDATE VISITOR'S LIST
    [self updateVisitotsLists];
 }
```

Is this proper ?

Comment: I would recommend using timers. 

Create an `NSTimer` property, but I would recommend calling `invalidate` on them on viewWillDisappear. If you don't call invalidate, when the view controller is dismissed or popped, it won't be deallocated, since NSTimer will keep it alive.

Comment: @LordZsolt, please check the added code in the question above.

Comment: @LordZsolt, can you put your answer as answer so I can mark as Solved.

Comment: @Tvd, you should move scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method call to viewWill(Did)Appear method. Because viewDidLoad is called not each time when screen is appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using timers.

Create an `NSTimer` property, but I would recommend calling `invalidate` on them on viewWillDisappear.

If you don't call invalidate, when the view controller is dismissed or popped, it won't be deallocated, since NSTimer will keep it alive.

The code you posted is fine with a few modifications:

- You don't need to @synthesize properties anymore (unless you overwrite both the setter and getter).
- Don't set timer to nil.

Edit: If you want the timer to be related to the screen (aka it should be executed only when the screen is visible), you should initialise in `viewDid(Will)Appear` and stop it in `viewDid(Will)Disappear`.